# For Loop Error Message

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, expression

```
public static  void FileReader(String[] parts)
        {
            while (inputFile.hasNext())
            {   

            String Line = inputFile.hasNext();  
                for (i<5)
                {
                    parts [i] = Line;
                    i++;
                }
        }

        System.out.println(parts.toString(full));
        }
}
```

according to the compiler the for loop is an illegal start of type.  I dont know what this error means or how to fix it.

Comment: String line = inputFile.next(); or inputFile.nextLine(); to get the line. Can you please show the complete code to show where you initialize the inputFile.

Comment: i think you mean to use the `while` loop

Comment: For loop requires local variable as a counter, boolean expression for end of this loop and then incrementing counter value in ich lap.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` or `int i = 0; while(i < 5) {... i++;}`

Answer (score 0):

You've defined your for-loop like this:

```
for (i<5)
{
  parts [i] = Line;
  i++;
}
```

This is the correct syntax for a `while` loop, not a for loop.

A for-loop would be defined like this:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5; i++) {
  parts[i] = Line;
}
```

---

The syntax of a for-loop looks like this:

```
for( <start condition> ; <end condition> ; <increment> )
```

So in the above example, the start condition declares the index variable, `i`, and initialized it to 0. The end condition, which defines when the loop will finish, is defined as `i = 5`; this means that the loop will stop once `i` reaches 5. The increment is simply `i++`, which will increase the value of `i` at the end of each loop.

---

The "illegal start of type" is probably coming from the fact that you're trying to use the `i` variable but haven't actually declared it. That is, you're missing the line that says `int i;`. (Ie: you haven't told the compiler what `i` *is*.) That's in addition to the blatantly wrong for-loop syntax that I've described above, of course.